# Program hangs after receiving proper result from child processes through pipe()

Tags: c, pipe, fork

I'm splitting a file, sending through `pipe()`, having children find the sum of their designated section of the file, returning the calculated sum to the parent through `pipe()`, and having the parent calculate the sum of the child sums.

I've got a working program.  My issues is that it hangs after receiving showing the proper final value.

I'm not sure what I'm doing to have the parent expect more information, but I'd bet it has something to do with my `for() loop` containing my child code.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int numchild;

int i, j, len, fpos=0, val, count=0, total=0, alltotal=0;
pid_t pid;
int nums = 1000;
FILE * file;

printf("How many children to use: ");
scanf("%d", &numchild);
printf("\nWill use %d child process(es).\n", numchild);

int fd[2*numchild][2]; //parent+child pipe

// create all pipes
for (i=0; i<2*numchild; i++)
{
    pipe(fd[i]);
}

for (i=0; i<numchild; i++)
{
    if((pid = fork()) == 0) // child process
    {
        pid = getpid();

        // read from parent
        len = read(fd[i][0], &fpos, sizeof(fpos));
        if (len > 0)
        {
            file = fopen("file1.dat", "r");
            fseek (file, fpos, SEEK_SET);
            count = 0;
            total = 0;

            printf("Child(%d): Recieved position: %d\n", pid, fpos);

            // read from file starting at fpos
            // add values read to a total value
            while (count < (nums/numchild))
            {
                fscanf(file, "%i", &val);
                total += val;
                count++;
            }
            //write to parent
            write(fd[i+numchild][1], &total, sizeof(total));
            printf("Child(%d): Sent %d to parent.\n", pid, total);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Child(%d): Error with len\n", pid);
        }

        _exit;
    }

    // parent process
    pid = getpid();

    fpos = ((i*nums*5)/numchild); // 5 is the offset of the file values

    // write to child process
    printf("Parent(%d): Sending file position to child\n", pid);
    write(fd[i][1], &fpos, sizeof(fpos));

    // wait for child responce
    len = read(fd[i+numchild][0], &total, sizeof(total));
    if (len > 0)
    {
        printf("Parent(%d): Recieved %d from child.\n", pid, total);
        alltotal += total;
        printf("Parent(%d): Total: %d\n", pid, alltotal);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Parent(%d): Error with len\n", pid);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What do you expect the statement `_exit;` to do? What does your compiler say about the line? *What say you now, demon?*

Comment: @EOF I assumed it signaled that the child process was complete.  Is it unnecessary?  And my compiler doesn't give me a message about it because it doesn't produce an error.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? How are you invoking the compiler? Where would `_exit` be declared?

Comment: @EOF I'm just using gcc.  I call it via the linux terminal.

Comment: You call `_exit` using something like `_exit(0);`. You just have `_exit;`, which takes the address of `_exit` and does nothing with it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't ask more questions, but if this is on Linux or Unix like systems (perhaps all posix):

You must do a `wait` (`man 2 wait`) for each of your child processes in your main program or you will create zombie processes.

Not knowing what environment you are running in makes it impossible for me to test this to determine if that is the cause of your not exiting properly.

Also (this is more like a comment), each cycle through the loop you are forking one child, then feeding it data, then getting a response, then printing the total. Is that really what you want to do? You don't need to create a bunch of pipes if you are only running one child at a time.

My guess is that you want to have some actual concurrency. You can do this by having a loop that creates all of the children followed by another loop that feeds them data, followed by a third loop that looks at the results and sums them, followed by a fourth loop that waits for each to terminate (to avoid zombies).

I would consider using `poll` or `select` to read the returns -- after all, there is no guarantee that the children will finish in order.

Comment: Would you be able to put together a short example for that?  I've got an idea, but I'm quite inexperienced with pipe() and how the parent and child programs interact.

Answer (score 0):

I won't select this as an answer until other people let me know this is probably what fixed it, but I believe that my program was hanging because the main() function wasn't actually returning anything.  When I went to put in time collection (save begin time, end time, calculate difference, output) it had to be done outside of my for loop, so it was the last statement right inside my main() method.  This seems to have stopped the hanging.

Answer (score 0):

Right after calling fork() in your if-statement, you need to call wait(). This makes causes your parent to wait for your child to exit, and then continue he execution when the child exits.